# how to concat html files and inject the css link in head section with a gulp plugin?

Tags: html, css, gulp

I have a folder structure like this:

```
src
   assets
       scss
           layout
               layout.scss
            pages
                index.scss
   layout
       site-header.html
       site-footer.html
    pages
        index.html
index.html
css
    layout.css
    index.css
js
```

The sass files in `/scss` folder is compiled to `/css` folder.

I linked the `/css/layout.css` in the `/src/layout/site-header.html` file.

The `/css/index.css` is linked in `/src/pages/index.html` file.

I want to use something(gulp plugin) to generate the `/index.html` in the root folder.

This file is comprised of the `/src/layout/site-header.html`, `/src/pages/index.html`, `/src/layout/site-footer.html`, and most importantly, put the `/css/index.css` link in the `head` part of the file.

How can I do this? I looked for gulp plugins, but I only find `https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include`, which cannot put the `css` link in the `head` section of the html file. :'(

Thanks in advance. :)

Please help to rephrase the title if it is inappropriate. :)

Answer (score 0):

:D I've found out I can use [gulp-file-include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include) to do the work :D

In the `/src/pages/index.html` I can pass the view css as in `json` format into layout file like this:

```
@@include('../layouts/site-header.html', {"viewCSS":"/css/pages/index.css"})
```

Then in `/src/layout/site-header.html` I can do:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@@viewCSS">
```

It outputs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/pages/index.css">
```

:)